# How to capture the time from textbox and paste it in excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, authentication

Employee login system using excel with macro.
An employee will enter employee ID and then display their name in txtName.  If they hit login button, I want to be able to capture the login time and paste it in excel sheet and then do vice versa when they logout.

Here's the screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

2nd screenshot for logout:
[image: Logout_issue]

Here's the code so far:

```
Dim CM As Boolean

Private Sub txtEmpID_Change()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range

Set mySheet = Sheets("Emp_ID")
Set myRange = mySheet.Range("B:B").Find(txtEmpID.Value, , , xlWhole)

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
txtName.Value = myRange.Offset(0, -1)
Else
txtName.Value = "Match not found"
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_activate()

Do
If CM = True Then Exit Sub
txtTime = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
DoEvents
Loop

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

CM = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you could post the code in your `CommandButton_Click` routine as that is the piece we need to be able to help you with this. You can simply edit this question  rather than start a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to use userform name for controls to avoid possible errors. Secondly, you can use `do loop` without using `if` like this:

```
Do While CM = False
UserForm1.txtTime = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
DoEvents
Loop
```

As for your question, here is how you pass values from textboxes to the last empty cells in your worksheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With Worksheets("Emp_ID").Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
    .Offset(1, 0) = UserForm1.txtName.Value
    .Offset(1, 1) = UserForm1.txtEmpID.Value
    .Offset(1, 2) = UserForm1.txtTime.Value
End With
Unload Me 'Optional: Close Userform1
End Sub
```

I don't follow you when you say *"and then do vice versa when they logout"* but if you want to record logout time as well, you do the same thing using logout button (CommandButton2):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Worksheets("Emp_ID").Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
Unload Me 'Optional: Close Userform On Where Logout Button Is
End Sub
```

Remember, to be able to pass textbox values to worksheet cells, userform should be open. You can not pass the values from a closed userform unless you pass them to a global variable before closing.

Comment: Tehscript thank you so much..I created a new sheet and store their login times there. The only problem that I have right now is during logout. I don't know how to put the logout time in the same row with the person who logs out.  I am thinking of using the code of .find(txtEmpID) then from there use the offset code.  I posted another screenshot, please feel free to check it out.

Comment: I already explained it in my solution. In your userform, create another button called CommandButton2 (Logout Button) and use the last code above. It should do the trick.

Comment: I think I got it already..I used the same code I used in txtEmpID_Change().

Comment: Tehscript I'm planning to add a short trappings. because a current login employee can still login.  I wanted to have a condition wherein they can only do logout when they're currently login. But anyway you really help me a lot.I appreciate it somuch.

Comment: @Dylan Mecagami I don't know what kind of user interface you are working on but you have lots of options for that. For example after login, you can close the userform for login and open another userform, which has logout button on it as well, and do the rest of the just here. Or if you want to use the same userform, you can change the visiblity of the button to false after loging in. There are many more options. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you. For now, I can't think of any code to put in. But I will see what I can do. I'll keep you posted when I have something to use.